# Simple 2 state button seems way more complicated than it needs to be - or am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, logic, imagebutton

I'm updating an existing site and learning as I go. The following code is for 2, 2-state buttons that I want to update. Visually they're the same, but the code for each is completely different and I'm wondering if anyone can help me understand why?

```
<ul class="clearfix">

                {if $smarty.session.userTypeCount > 1}

                    {assign var="switchActivCls" value=""}

                    {if $currentfilename eq "profileSwitch.php"}

                        {assign var="switchActivCls" value="active"}

                    {/if}

                    <li class="proSwitch">

                        <a href="{$pubmenu.profileSwitch}" class="{$switchActivCls}"><span class="link-underline">Switch Profile</span></a>                     

                    </li>

                {else}

                    <li>&nbsp;</li>

                    <li>&nbsp;</li>

                {/if}                   

                    <div id="logOut" class="logOut">

                        <li><a href="{$pubmenu.logout}"><img src="{$image_path}icons/exit.svg" width="18" height="18" alt="Logout" /></a></li>

                        <li><a href="{$pubmenu.logout}"><span class="link-underline">Logout</span></a></li>

                    </div>

                    <div id="logOut1" class="logOut" style="display:none">

                        <li><a href="{$pubmenu.logout}"><img src="{$image_path}icons/exit-ovr.svg" width="18" height="18" alt="Logout"/></a></li>

                        <li><a href="{$pubmenu.logout}"><span class="link-underline">Logout</span></a></li>

                    </div>



            </ul>
```

The first is pretty much as I'd expect, although I don't know why there are li's and blank spaces in the else statement. Wouldn't it have been better to use the existing class variable to hide/show the content, rather than leave empty li's on the page?

The second seems more unusual; 2 divs, 4 li's, 4 a tags, a couple of images and some styles hard coded into the logic, seems strange for a single button that's essentially the same as the one above it. I can see that the code pulls in the href and image path, but doesn't appear to be doing anything special, so I'm wondering why the extra effort/code? Does anyone have any ideas why these buttons would have been coded this way - best practice, browser support or something else??

Ideally I want to update both buttons to use something like this:

```
<a class="icon-link" href="{$pubmenu.logout}"><svg class="fa-icon" role="image" alt="logout" aria-hidden="true"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#fa-icon"></use></svg>Name</a>
```

The above is the method used by [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/#docs/inline-svg) and [Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/), so it should be good and seems to work elsewhere on my site (only tested locally). But feel free to let me know if you have any other recommendations - everyday's a school day :)

Thanks so much in advance.